# Dirac Hamiltonian and Topological Insulators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, dirac-equation, topological-insulators

Specifically, why do we treat the Bloch Hamiltonian in a topological insulator (TI) as a two level system that possesses a linear dispersion relationship? What justifies this effective model? I can't find any sources that explains the relationship in a way that draws from first principles or provides a firm Solid State foundation. Most reviews on the subject seem to *begin* the discussion with a $2\times2$ relativistic matrix Hamiltonian, but I have not seen where this would come from using Solid State fundamentals. Topological nature and edge states follow from this treatment as well, so the explanation should not incorporate these facts as principles which then justify the treatment we used to derive them.

For example, some sources explain that it is the strong Spin-Orbit (SO) coupling that makes this necessary; however, SO is present for all systems as a first-order relativistic correction. So, we can hypothetically treat ANY system with a $2\times2$ Hamiltonian (i.e. Pauli Hamiltonian). This correction does not linearize momentum either, i.e. $\alpha p^2\rightarrow \alpha p^2-\beta p^4$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants.

Other sources say that one makes a series expansion around Dirac points, keeping only the first order term in the series; however, this expansion can be done for any point in the BZ. For any crystal momentum, we can approximate the neighborhood around that point with a linear dispersion, but that doesn't imply that the Bloch Hamiltonian is relativistic. Additionally, bands cross the Fermi level in many kinds of non topological materials. So, I could hypothetically expand around a crossing within a non topological material and treat low energy states with a Dirac type Hamiltonian as well.

When implementing a first principles analytical band structure calculation for Graphene, one finds that the material possesses two Dirac points in the BZ, and it is said that the Bloch Hamiltonian resembles the Dirac Hamiltonian near these points. In order for this to happen, the Bloch Hamiltonian should be $2\times2$ in the case of Weyl fermions. However, the fact that this Hamiltonian is $2\times2$ comes from the crystal basis used to solve a Tight-Binding model of Graphene.

Essentially, I ask the question: What is special about topological insulators that make this treatment necessary?